# How to align text to center this image?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGgWLx)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 tab-bottom">
                    <div class="tab-bottom-img"><img width="380" height="380" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1-380x380.png" class="attachment-news wp-post-image" alt="1"> </div>
                        <div class="tab-bottom-content">
                            SED PERSPICIATIS                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit<br>
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,<br>
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore<br>
veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt<br>
explicabo.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.tab-bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Image width and height will vary ... he should always be in the middle

I tried to align text center but not working...

Text must be aligned both horizontally and vertically.

Can you help me to solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following CSS:

```
.tab-bottom-content {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top: -240px;
    margin-left: 20px;; 
}
```

Before, you had `top: 0;` which means to show the div in the `0 pixels` from main port. If you want to change bring the text in the middle of it then change the value for `top` CSS property. If the Image and Div are not the first elements on your page, then I suggest to use `margin` instead of `top` property.

Comment: yes but want the text to be aligned left ... but  in center the image

Comment: And vertically centered? How do?

Comment: @Marius Updated again. check it

Comment: Image width and height will vary <-- this answer doesn't work if img dimensions change unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (https://jsfiddle.net/g6r8ayq1/1/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4 tab-bottom">
                    <div class="tab-bottom-img"><img width="380" height="380" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/1-380x380.png" class="attachment-news wp-post-image" alt="1"> </div>
                        <div class="tab-bottom-content">
                            SED PERSPICIATIS                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit<br>
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,<br>
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore<br>
veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt<br>
explicabo.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 }
 .tab-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;

 }
.tab-bottom-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

 }
.tab-bottom-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: yes but want the text to be aligned left ... but  in center the image

Comment: Fixed it. Now aligns both horizontically and vertically. As requested, it works with variable image height and width